# $(X_1,X_2)$ have uniform distribution on the triangle ${0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq 1}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

We are interested in the distribution of $Y= X_1 + X_2$. I post pictures of the example. I am having hard time wrapping my head around the case of when $1 \leq y \leq 2$, this is shown in part 2. Can anyone explain the bounds of the integral for this case?

[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]
[image: Part 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct but to solve the exercise no integral are needed. As you can see in the following solution, $F_Y$ can be derived with very simple areas calculations

Observe the following drawing

[image]

The CDF when $0<Y<1$ in the left drawing is the area of the purple triangle multiplied by the joint density, thus

$$F_Y(y)=2\cdot \frac{y}{2} \cdot \frac{y}{2}=\frac{y^2}{2}$$

When $1<Y<2$ it is easy to calculate $P(Y>y)$ first, that is the area of the purple triangle (in the right drawing) multiplied by the joint density and then get its complement to 1 to obtain the CDF, thus

$$F_Y(y)=1-2\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)\frac{2-y}{2}=1-\frac{(2-y)^2}{2}$$

Concluding:

$$ F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y<0$} \\
\frac{y^2}{2},  & \text{if $0\leq y<1$} \\
1-\frac{(2-y)^2}{2},  & \text{if $1\leq y<2$} \\
1,  & \text{if $y\geq 2$} 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks so much for the help.